# Azure Cognitive Services Computer Vision to count the number of pipes

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

Could I customize Azure Cognitive Services Computer Vision to count the number of the following pipes?
Thanks. 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft Computer Vision does not currently return the count of an item.  However we appreciate seeing these type of requests and questions to help us improve the service.

Comment: Appreciated. This can really save numerously precious time to count these pipes for the enterprise.